# Reference request: existence of strong solutions to a linear parabolic problem with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: parabolic-pde, linear-pde

on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$ subdivided into two parts $\Gamma_D$ and $\Gamma_N$ I am considering the parabolic problem
$$
\partial_t u = \Delta u + b(x,t)\cdot \nabla u = f(x,t)
$$
with 
$$
u = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma_D \text{ and } \partial_n u = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma_D,
$$
and with initial conditions 
$$
u(x,0) = u_0(x) \text{ on } \Omega
$$
Both the  coefficient $b(x,t)$ and $f(x,t)$ are in $L^\infty((0,T);L^\infty(\Omega))$ in space and time.

I am looking for a results that, under suitable assumptions on $\Gamma_N,\,\Gamma_D$ and $u_0$ garuantees the existence of solutions 
$$
u \in L^p((0,T);W^{2,p}(\Omega))\cap W^{1,p}((0,T);L^p(\Omega)).
$$
For the elliptic problem, I found such a result e.g. in [Troianello, Elliptic Differential Equations and Obstacle Problems], however, for the parabolic counterpart there are papers which treat the $L^2$-setting (e.g. [Savare, Parabolic problems with mixed variable
lateral conditions: an abstract approach] which even deals with the more complicated situation of time varying boundary) or Papers by Lieberman which deal with H\"older regularity. 
However, I fail to find the result for my specific situation.

Many thanks